# crontab exclude specific date only

Tags: cron

How can I write a cron that will exclude a specific date.

let say : I need to run a crontab 6pm to 9pm in every 30 min on weekends and want to exclude 10th may 2014 only.

Is It possible? How can I write this? or is any alternative for this? please suggest.

Comment: homework problem?

Comment: @mdpc : I have searched a lot and didn't get proper solution for it. I know about the cron but don't know how to exclude a particular date. If you have any idea please share.

Answer (score 6):

Standard cron syntax is quite simple, it does not support exclusions.
In some cases it is possible to create a list of several/many cron entries to implement such logic, but that tends be tedious and hard to understand or maintain; this approach is not applicable in your case though (not least because standard cron has no notion of the calendar year).

It's not a great plan to make cron commands complicated, but you can do this with something relatively straightforward like:

```
0,30 18-20 * * sat,sun [ "$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)" = "20140510" ] || mycommand
0    21    * * sat,sun [ "$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)" = "20140510" ] || mycommand
```

(With "`0,30 18-21`" the task would also run at 21:30; you need the second line if you wish to run also at 21:00, if not then omit it)

NOTE: In [some crontabs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/crontab.html) you must escape percentage signs (they are used to indicate newlines when stuffing inline data into standard input of the command), though not in Dillon's cron.

The cron command is really a shell *command list*, the `||` control operator provides [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of commands. Commands in the list are attempted one at a time, from left to right, but the execution stops when first one returns true.
If the date string comparison returns true (only true for one day) `mycommand` is not run, when the date comparison returns false `mycommand` is run.

Note however, many things can differ in the way cron starts programs. The most robust approach is to use a wrapper script to implement your conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `X-Y` for time intervals and `*/Z` for frequencies. Where:

- `X` is the start of the interval.
- `Y` is the end of the interval.
- `Z` is just a divisor (i.e.: each `Z`).

For excluding a date I would just create my own script. Within this script, check date and then decide if you want to execute the following instruction(s).

Comment: The same way I am assuming I need to create a own script to exclude a specific date..Can't do using cron. Thanks.